# Is there any place where I can buy English dubbed (The very first vintage one) Captain Tsubasa anime series?

Tags: merchandise, streaming-sites, captain-tsubasa

I am not able to find the English dubbed anime of The original Captain Tsubasa series (Starting with Tsubasa's transfer to Nankatsu till finals between Tsubasa and Hyuga).

Is there any place where I could buy it or watch by paying?